# I can not notify to honeybadger

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sinatra

I tried to notify exception from Grape API in my rails application to honeybadger, but it doesn't work.

```
# api_error_handler.rb
module API
  module V1
    module Config
      class ApiErrorHandler < Grape::Middleware::Base
        def call!(env)
          @env = env
          begin
            @app.call(@env)
          rescue StandardError => e
            Honeybadger.notify(e)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


# In defaults.rb
module API
  module V1
    module Defaults
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      included do
        error_formatter :json, API::V1::Config::ErrorFormatter
        rescue_from     :all, backtrace: true
        use API::V1::Config::ApiErrorHandler

        helpers do
          def authenticate_user!
              ...
          end
        end
      end
    .....
    end
  end
end
```

I included defaults.rb in each specific api.

Thanks for any helping!

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions never propagate to the `API::V1::Config::ApiErrorHandler` because they are swallowed by `rescue_from :all, backtrace: true`.

You can have your own exception handling in a `rescue_from` block.

```
rescue_from :all do |e|
  Honeybadger.notify(e)

  # Error still formatted with error_formatter
  # message, status, headers, backtrace
  error! e.message, 500, {}, e.backtrace
end
```

Sources:

- `rescue_from :all` : [Grape documentation](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/tree/fd8578458260fec1724c4e45b0b72cdcd9162ad5#exception-handling)
- `error!` interface: [Grape source](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/152fa4045af039a736dedb046be3a01d19af904a/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb#L80-L83)